# can't login to dropbox - version issue

Tags: 14.04, updates, update-manager, dropbox, versions

I run Ubuntu 14 LTS, and ran get update and get upgrade just now,

I have a user that runs Dropbox, and it is running great,

I created a new user and try to link it to Dropbox too and getting some weird massage that i can't sign in to Dropbox because my version is not updated, but it works great on the old user, i tried to disconnect and reconnect and it works well.

I can't seem to find any update for Dropbox in the software center...

Is this is a known bug?

Answer (score 1):

Try getting a fresh release from:

https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx

Make sure that your browser is logged out from dropbox.com when you visit this link; otherwise download links are not shown.

Comment: but how is that even possible, same dropbox, one user of ok and the other is not.

Comment: Seems like the dropbox version available on Ubuntu Software Repo is not the latest one. The official downloaded .deb will add a ppa making sure that your dropbox is always updated. The version available through official download is v6.4.14.

Comment: that was weird, i reinstalled it and every thing is ok now

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting a fresh version from the Dropbox site, i removed it and reinstalled using the Ubuntu software center, and now it works.